javascript strange results getting nearest colours from array
I am using this script to find nearest color from a list/array of colors.
nearest.js
const colors = ["#FFFFFF", "#520975", "#5D0C8B", "#777779"];
const hexToRgb = hex => hex.slice(1).replace(/^(.)(.)(.)$/gi, "$1$1$2$2$3$3").match(/.{2}/g).map(c => parseInt(c, 16));
const distance = (a, b) => Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a[0] - b[0], 2) + Math.pow(a[1] - b[1], 2) + Math.pow(a[2] - b[2], 2));
const nearestColor = colorHex => colors.reduce((a,v,i,arr) => a = distance(hexToRgb(colorHex), hexToRgb(v)) < a[0] ? [distance(hexToRgb(colorHex), hexToRgb(v)), v] : a, [Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, colors[0]])[1];

Something is wrong here..
nearestColor("#854B97"); this should return one of this two #520975, #5D0C8B instead it returns a grey color #777779
here is a demo pen  https://codepen.io/templatetuners/pen/RwOeLxz

Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [<>] snippet editor.

The gray color is closer to that color than the other two, by the vector distance formula you're using. If you want similarity that's more accurate to how humans perceive color you'll have to use a more sophisticated formula.

can you give me an example of a library or so? thanks

Type "color similarity equation" into Google Search

Here is a CIELAB version https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/kqb4j0ep/

@mplungjan can you post this to mark as solved? thanks for solution

Here is a CIELAB version that seems to work better


/**
 * Converts a hexadecimal color value to an RGB array.
 * @param {string} hex - The hexadecimal color string (e.g., "#FFFFFF").
 * @returns {number[]} An array containing the RGB values [red, green, blue].
 */
const hexToRgb = hex => {
  const r = parseInt(hex.slice(1, 3), 16);
  const g = parseInt(hex.slice(3, 5), 16);
  const b = parseInt(hex.slice(5, 7), 16);
  return [r, g, b];
};

/**
 * Converts an RGB color array into an XYZ color array using the sRGB color space.
 * @param {number[]} rgb - An array of RGB values [red, green, blue].
 * @returns {number[]} An array containing the XYZ values.
 */
const rgbToXyz = rgb => {
  let [r, g, b] = rgb.map(v => {
    v /= 255;
    return v > 0.04045 ? Math.pow((v + 0.055) / 1.055, 2.4) : v / 12.92;
  });

  [r, g, b] = [r * 100, g * 100, b * 100];
  const x = r * 0.4124 + g * 0.3576 + b * 0.1805;
  const y = r * 0.2126 + g * 0.7152 + b * 0.0722;
  const z = r * 0.0193 + g * 0.1192 + b * 0.9505;
  return [x, y, z];
};

/**
 * Converts an XYZ color array to a CIELAB color array which more closely aligns with human color perception.
 * @param {number[]} xyz - An array of XYZ values.
 * @returns {number[]} An array containing the CIELAB values [L*, a*, b*].
 */
const xyzToLab = xyz => {
  let [x, y, z] = xyz;
  [x, y, z] = [x / 95.047, y / 100.000, z / 108.883];
  [x, y, z] = [x, y, z].map(v => v > 0.008856 ? Math.pow(v, 1 / 3) : (7.787 * v) + (16 / 116));

  const l = (116 * y) - 16;
  const a = 500 * (x - y);
  const b = 200 * (y - z);
  return [l, a, b];
};

/**
 * Calculates the Delta E (Euclidean distance in the LAB color space) color difference between two CIELAB colors.
 * @param {number[]} labA - The first CIELAB color array.
 * @param {number[]} labB - The second CIELAB color array.
 * @returns {number} The Delta E color difference.
 */
const deltaE = (labA, labB) => {
  return Math.sqrt(
    Math.pow(labA[0] - labB[0], 2) +
    Math.pow(labA[1] - labB[1], 2) +
    Math.pow(labA[2] - labB[2], 2)
  );
};

/**
 * Finds the nearest color from a predefined set to the given hexadecimal color.
 * @param {string} colorHex - The hexadecimal color code.
 * @returns {string} The hexadecimal code of the nearest color from the set.
 */
const nearestColor = colorHex => {
  const targetLab = xyzToLab(rgbToXyz(hexToRgb(colorHex)));
  return colors.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const currLab = xyzToLab(rgbToXyz(hexToRgb(curr)));
    const currDeltaE = deltaE(targetLab, currLab);
    return currDeltaE < acc.deltaE ? { color: curr, deltaE: currDeltaE } : acc;
  }, { color: null, deltaE: Infinity }).color;
};

/** Test the code **/
var nearest = nearestColor('#854B97');
document.getElementById("near").innerHTML = "result<br>" + nearest;
document.getElementById("near").style.backgroundColor = nearest;
<title>Color Distance in CIELAB</title>
<div style="background:#520975; width:100px; height:100px; display:block; float:left; margin:0;">#520975<br>array color</div>
<div style="background:#5D0C8B; width:100px; height:100px; display:block; float:left; margin:0;">#5D0C8B<br>array color</div>
<div style="clear:both;background:#854B97; width:100px; height:100px; display:block; float:left; margin:0;">#854B97<br>find near for this color</div>
<div id="near" style="width:100px; height:100px; display:block; float:left; margin:0;"></div>

<script>
  const colors = [
    "#B2CFAD", "#F4C6CE", "#7CADD3", "#A4C7E2", "#1BCFC9", "#F7EA5F", "#ffffff", "#520975", "#004987", "#F5E500",
    "#FF8300", "#D8262E", "#999899", "#016836", "#005CB8", "#008995", "#D08900", "#EF8F7A", "#F0B2C9", "#EA534D",
    "#823550", "#98C11E", "#009ADD", "#FF8188", "#AA7BC9", "#E7E6E5", "#4D9C2D", "#C5093B", "#D7006D", "#970047",
    "#10576C", "#00CAC3", "#F1F0E2", "#8FC6E8", "#004876", "#FF637D", "#2E5BBE", "#B0A198", "#FFBE9E", "#7B2F3E",
    "#EB6BAF", "#F2F0A1", "#B9AAD4", "#86ad3f", "#AFC9B8", "#D1CCBD", "#D25D12", "#ECCCCE", "#F3CD00", "#006547",
    "#789D90", "#80A7BC", "#B8C7D3", "#AF90A7", "#777779", "#5D0C8B", "#01426A", "#F6CE3C", "#00AFA9", "#E11282",
    "#F3D09E", "#00A6CE", "#F8B5CC", "#32393C", "#FFDB00", "#EB0028", "#F0B2C9", "#FF6B0B", "#C4D5EC"
  ];
</script>



